# How to pass arguments to a python script on a button press from vb

Tags: python, vba, button

I have been trying something like this in VB.

Private Sub python_Click()
    Shell "C:\Python25\python.exe ""C:\rowcount.py"
End Sub

This python script just creates a text file and this script works fine. But how to run a python script from vb button_click event as if the python script accepts run-time arguments.

Something like the following
e.g:  Shell "C:\Python25\python.exe ""C:\rowcount.py -e -w -v COM6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Windows just call the Python file by itself. If you're on Mac or *Nix then make it executeable with chmod a+x pythonfile.py, then call it.

You may need to add python to the Path environment variable but that is always a convenient thing to have.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "calling python by itself"

Comment: Call Shell("path\pyfile.py")